# PHP Zend test dump need help understanding

Tags: php, regex, zend-framework, preg-match

How many elements does the $matches array contain after the following function call is
performed?

this('/^(\d{1,2}([a-z]+))(?:\s*)\S+ (?=200[0-9])/', '21st March
2006', $matches);

A.
1

B.
2

C.
3

D.
4

I know the answer is C. What I can't figure out how you get their. From what I can tell and figure out I understand how we get 21st March. I don't get how you get 21st and st. If this can be explain to me.

Comment: In reality you would use `strtotime` for this though, right?

Answer (score 2):

```
'/^(\d{1,2}([a-z]+))(?:\s*)\S+ (?=200[0-9])/'
```

Is read as 3 matches.

```
(\d{1,2}([a-z]+))
```

is the first one. The regex returns only the first level of the expression, so it resolves the match as

```
(\d{1,2}st)
```

in your case.

second and third are

```
(?:\s*)
```

and

```
(?=200[0-9])
```

If you want to get your 'st' as another match, I guess you should use

```
'/^(\d{1,2})([a-z]+)(?:\s*)\S+ (?=200[0-9])/'
```

as your regex